# How to dry/preserve whole oranges

Tags: food-preservation, oranges

I recently made an orange pomander ball and I want to dry it so that I can use it in the future but I live in a fairly foggy and dreary area so it would be hard to simply set it out. Does anyone have any suggestions for drying oranges in my case and in general?

Comment: I do a lot of dehydrating and I'm not sure this is doable due to the size of the fruit. When you dry things they have to have a way to let the moisture escape. With whole oranges (even with the cuts in the skin) I don't see how it would be possible. Maybe someone else knows of a way. I'd be interested.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about oranges as *food*, but about crafting. There is the proposed [Arts and Crafts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts) which might be happy about this question.

Comment: I'd freeze dry (lyophilize), but you need a vacuum chamber, pump, and cold trap for that.